# Does circumcision mean that body is not "perfect" by default?

Tags: creation, human-body, circumcision

Salam,

If circumcision makes the body safe and cleaner, does it mean that the men body is not well done by default ?

Salem

Comment: I am not sure what this is supposed to mean. We cut our nails. Does that mean the body is not perfect?

Comment: Baraka Allahou fik, smart answer @TheZ

Comment: Baraka Allahou fik, smart answer @TheZ

Answer (score 1):

Circumcision is a very old ritual. According to the scriptures it has been introduced by Abraham, the rule in Arabia related to Ismael a.s. has become the ritual in Islam.
It is also known in many countries in Africa before Islam,  in fact circumcision is also practiced among Christians in many African countries not from Christian teachings but from old rites. I know that in Kenya also Christians circumcise at the same age,  at least before 11 years old but not as small Children as in Judaism.
Circumcision reduces the risk of inflammation but removes the protection against physical impact. Others also live well without circumcision. Maybe it would not be necessary with modern medicine, asinflammation is healed easier than in ancienttimes,  but it is an old ritual become a general rule for Islam, and there is nothing wrong with it.